# VS Code Doesn't Recognize Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using VS Code on a Mac to write Python code.  I've created a virtual environment named 'venv' inside my project folder and opened VS Code in my project folder.  I can see the venv folder in the Explorer pane.  However, if I install a package into the virtual environment and I try to import the package into a Python module and then run the module, VS Code raises a ModuleNotFound error saying there is no module.

I followed the instructions in the VS Code document [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) by opening the Command Palette, choosing Python: Select Interpreter, and then selecting "venv/bin/folder".  But when I do that, I get this error:

```
Failed to set 'pythonPath'. Error: Unable to write into folder settings.  Please open the 'my_project' folder settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.
```

What are these "folder settings?" I don't see anything in the document I cited above that talks about a folder setting for my virtual environment directory.

**Environment:**
VS Code 1.35.1
Python for VS Code 0.2.3
Python 3.7.1

**UPDATE**

Taking @khuynh advice, I opened settings.json and found one error which was that I tried to comment out a line with "//".  I didn't realize that JSON files can't include comments.

After taking that line out, I ran "Python: Select Interpreter" again but this time a tab that says `.vscode > settings.json >> code-runner.executorMap.python` at the top appeared.  The tab contained the following code:

```
    {
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
        "code-runner.executorMap.python": "python3 -u"
    }
```

There is a red squiggly line beneath "code-runner.executorMap.python" and the Problems window below says "Unknown configuration setting."  I don't understand what's wrong with this setting.

Comment: It looks like there could be an error in your `settings.json`. Try opening up your command palette using `cmd+shift+p` and then type in "settings" and select the option "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and look for any red squiggly lines indicating an error. I'd double check your paths to make sure they are correct as well

Comment: I took your advice which helped clear up one error but I still have a second error as I described in the UPDATE section above.

Comment: In your error, there should be a comma after the first key-value pair. So you should change that line to: `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",`.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that now is called `python.defaultInterpreterPath`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31077238)

Answer (score 3):

Selecting a Python Interpreter does not work if you have errors in your workplace settings file. You are missing a comma after your "python.pythonPath" line.

(I see that others answered this in comments, but I wanted to post an Answer to make this easier for others to find.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you opened a Python file directly versus opening the folder containing the file. If you do the latter then you can specify the Python interpreter in your settings.

Otherwise you may have permission errors that are preventing creating the `.vscode`folder to save your settings.

Answer (score 2):

To set up Visual Studio Code on a Mac with a python virtual environment edit the JSON workspace settings in Visual Studio Code with the shortcut "**command + shift + p**"

[image: Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)]

In Visual Studio Code Version: 1.45.1 the workspace.json settings look like this:

```
{
    "folders": [
          {
              "path": "/Users/me/Documents/Projects/djangoproject"
          }
      ],
      "settings": {
          "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/virtualenvs/djangovenv/bin/python3"
      }
}
```

This will automatically activate the python virtual environment when a new bash terminal is opened on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just now, I reopened a VS Code workspace on an external drive after moving from work PC to home PC and encountered this error.

I solved it by opening VS code settings  cmd+shift+p and then type in "settings" and select the option "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

then I edited the line:
`"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python37\\python3.exe",`

to the following (check the path to python executable):
`"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python37\\python.exe",`

to fix.

**Update:**
What occurred to me is that I may face this issue again when I access the project from my work computer next week as I have a different python version installed there. Will post outcome

Comment: please post the outcome

Answer (score 0):

For me the python plugin in wsl2 was missing. Installing that and changing to python.defaultInterpreterPath (new) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you already installed Python extension on your VS Code.
   Here is the link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

[image]

2. `python.pythonPath` seems changed to `python.defaultInterpreterPath`

---

Another way is you can use **SHIFT + COMMAND + P** then select interpreter.

[image]

This is my settings file. Hope it helpful to someone.

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.banditEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": false,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length", "250", "--experimental"],
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "indent",
    "editor.autoIndent": "keep",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "tab.activeBackground": "#777a7a"
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
    },
    "[yaml]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "other": true,
            "comments": false,
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.autoIndent": "keep"
    },
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "editor.rulers": [
        {
            "column": 120,
            "color": "#424142"
        },
    ],
}
```