# Why am I constantly asked to select a python interpreter over and over again?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, wsl-2, rhel7

I'm running VsCode on Windows 10 in "WSL" mode with a RHEL7 distribution in WSL2.
Every time I startup, I get prompted, "No Python interpreter is selected. You need to select a Python interpreter to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging.
Source: Python Extension. Select a Python Interpreter."
Each time I select it, and then next time it asks me again.
What is going on? Is this intended behavior?
Is this a bug?

Comment: May be this post help you. > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652968/vs-code-doesnt-recognize-python-virtual-environment#56915034

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by VSCode not having write perms in your workspace. Running it as admin may fix your problem